# Why would a C++ compiler only eliminate useless writes if there's no code after those writes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, optimization, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I'm inspecting Visual C++ 10 optimization capabilities and found a rather curious thing. All code herein is compiled with /O2.

In the following code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char buffer[1024] = {};
    MessageBoxA( 0, buffer, buffer, 0 );
    memset( buffer, 0, sizeof( buffer ) );
    return 0;
}
```

the call to `memset()` before `return` is eliminated from the machine code (I inspect the disassembly). This is perfectly reasonable - if there're no reads from `buffer` afterwards then `memset()` is useless and if the developers really want to overwrite the buffer thay can use [`SecureZeroMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

However in the following code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char buffer[1024] = {};
    MessageBoxA( 0, buffer, buffer, 0 );
    memset( buffer, 0, sizeof( buffer ) );
    Sleep( 0 ); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Extra code
    return 0;
}
```

the call to `memset()` is not eliminated. That call has no influence on observed behavior and could be eliminated just as well as in the first snippet.

This can be a compiler deficiency or it can be useful somehow - I can't decide.

Why could leaving `memset()` call in the machine code emitted for the second snippet be useful?

Comment: You know that Sleep() has no side-effects.  How is the compiler supposed to know?

Comment: @HansPassant: How would `Sleep()` be affected by a local variable that it is unaware of?

Comment: @sharptooth: The address of buffer is passed to other functions, which are allowed to store it a global or static variable that Sleep may be able to access.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The compiler probably can't tell that `MessageBoxA` doesn't create an alias to `buffer` that's then used by `Sleep` later. Thus it fails the "as-if" check.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can look at the contents of `memset` and determine what it does.  `Sleep()` is a system call that interacts with the kernel and its behavior is dependent on what version of Windows the code is run on; including the possibility of yet to implemented versions of Windows.  There is simply no way for the compiler to know what the function will do and therefore there is no way for it optimize around it.

The same can be said of `MessageBox` which makes me surprised that `memset` got removed in the first version.

It is a safe bet that the call to `memset` will not be a problem on any current or future version of Windows, but that's not something I want the compiler to try to guess about.

Comment: in the first version, the `memset` is called after `MessageBoxA`. Thus does not influence it. We could argue that `MessageBoxA` could have posted the address to something that is watching it, but the C++ virtual machine makes no timing guarantees, so eliminating the call is akin to simply waiting for an infinite time before returning. TL;DR only instruction *after* the call to `memset` may influence the optimizer.

Comment: @Matthieu M. I don't agree. If the compiler could be sure that the local buffer isn't "leaked" (ie some method saves its address) it could easily remove the memset even if Sleep() is called afterwards. So functions BEFORE the memset can as well influence the optimizer.

Comment: @Voo: yes obviously, that would be a `Dead Store`. My summary was not intended to sound as general as it does.

Comment: @Voo: If outside code got an an alias to `buffer` (which it could have, via the `MessageBox` call), it could legitimately use it as long as it had some way of knowing the method hadn't returned yet.  Without the `Sleep` call, even if `buffer` would still exist during the `memset`, outside code would have no way of knowing that the method hadn't returned and thus would not be able to legitimately access it.  While `Sleep()` is executing, however, outside code would know `buffer` still exists.